# Length of a 2-dimensional array / matrix

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

So I would like to construct a program that receives the elements of two matrices and gives out the product of these two matrices. I experimented a little bit so far, created a matrix and used the "readInts"-manual. First, I would like to make sure that the program actually receives the elements typed in by the user, so I wanted to print out the first matrix as a whole (and then go further, of course). This is included in this code:

```
int rows = readInt("Number of rows: ");
int columns = readInt("Number of columns: ");
int [][] m = new int[rows][columns];
int [] elements = readInts("Please type in the elements: ");

for(int = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
 print(elements[i], 5);
}
```

Now, what I didn't understand yet is how I have to interpret "m.length". After a little bit of testing, I found out that it refers to the number of rows, so for example when I define 3 rows and type in the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, I receive only 1, 2, 3, so the program cuts off the rest. I guess he actually is supposed to refer to the number of columns, so I'd have to switch [rows] and [columns] when I define m, but that's counterintuitive since you always name the number of rows first. Plus, I don't know whether there would arise other problems with that sooner or later or not. So, is there another way to do this without switching [rows] and [columns] at the beginning?

Comment: What are `readInt` and `readInts`? These are not standard Java methods...

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. "readInt" reads in an integer while "readInts" reads in several integers one after another. When you print those elements, they are in the same row from the very beginning.

Comment: You should know 1 thing before going any further. In java if you create two dimensional arrays like that, that array is not necessarily equivalent to matrice. Especially if you are filling array from console row by row etc. A two dimensional array is simply an array of array types and length of each array can be different if you are not careful with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you know the rows and columns you can do 2 for loops.

```
int rows = readInt("rows");
int columns =readInt("columns");
int [][] m = new int[rows][columns];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    int n[]=readInts("enter 3 numbers:");
    for (int k = 0; k < columns; k++) {
        m[i][k] = n[k];
    }
}
```

There is no need to use the scanner like i did(isn't working properly here). yet 
this should give you the desired result if you read the strings right

Comment: This gives me "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3  at Matrix.main(Matrix.java:15)".

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. I have to type in 9 numbers directly. But actually, the user is supposed to type them in row for row, so he is supposed to type in 3 numbers, then Enter, then again 3 numbers and so on.

Comment: and that input should be stored only in m? or also in elements?

Comment: Only in m. My plan is to do this whole thing for two different matrices in the end in order to multiplicate them. So, for example, when the user chooses  3 rows and 3 columns, he should type in 3 numbers, Enter, type in 3 numbers, Enter, type in 3 numbers. This is supposed to be my first matrix then.

Comment: did you implement that method? if yes post it please

Comment: It's part of the tools we use at our university, I guess.

Comment: what tools you use?

Comment: It's called "AlgoTools".

Comment: good i update the code once again so it matches with the tools you use. now it should work as desired

Comment: if i understand the methods right then yes. fixed some little mistakes so maybe copy code again. are you studying in karlsruhe?

Comment: ahh okay. no problem